# C programming typing out a list that's modded out by 10

Tags: c

I am trying to work on a program where the user enters a random number and the program enters a list from 0 to 9.

For example, say that the user enters the number 12 then the screen should look like this:

0123456789012

Where '2' at the end indicates the 12th number. I've tried this but it gives me an infinite loop and I don't know how to tell it to stop:

```
for(i = 0; i < cells; i++) {
i = i%10;
printf("%d", i);
}
```

The cells here is the number that the user enters.

Comment: Step through this code in a debugger (or just run it on paper) and watch what happens to `i`. Think about the two different jobs that `i` is doing in this code and whether that's part of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are changing `i` in the loop.  You must iterate as many times as the input.  You're almost there, but you loop forever because you are modifying `i` in such a way that it will never be larger than or equal to `cells` for `cells > 10`.

Try this:

```
for( int i = 0; i < cells; ++i ) {
    printf( "%d", i % 10 );
}
```

Also...

> 0123456789012
>
> Where '2' at the end indicates the 12th number.

The second `2` is the 13th number, not the 12th :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't modify the original variable inside the loop!  Create a new variable to hold the value of `i%10`.

Comment: When I put i = i%10; outside of the loop the program ignores it

Comment: @NeedarealJob: You need to study up on variable lifetime and scope.

Comment: If you truly don't understand what is happening then take a pencil and sheet of paper and run through the program yourself modifying i as you go, and you will discover what the problem is and why.

Comment: I didn't realize that we could say i%10 in the printf line. I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to set `i = i%10`. Create another variable and set *that* to `i%10`

Answer (score 1):

When you do `i = i%10;` you actually alter the contents of `i` which the loop is using to count. What you should be doing instead is either calculating the mod inside the printf like

`printf("%d", i%10);`

or storing the mod in another variable and printing that like

```
mod_i = i % 10;
printf("%d", mod_i);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `i = i%10`; you are changing the value of `i` to `i % 10`. So `cells` is greater 10, at some point i will have the value 10 at the start of the loop and then be assigned the value 0 (`10 % 10`). Hence your loop will repeat forever since `i < cells` will always be false.

The solution is to delete the assignment entirely and just `printf("%d", i % 10)`.