# C program need help fixing my code (Concept of arrays)

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C programming: Occupying Cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077759/c-programming-occupying-cells)
>   [C programming typing out a list that's modded out by 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100253/c-programming-typing-out-a-list-thats-modded-out-by-10)

I have worked on this code for a week now and haven't managed to get any kind of success. The program is supposed to ask the user to enter in a number of cells. The user is then prompted over which of cells s/he would like occupied. The program then puts a '?' underneath the occupied cell(s) indicated. I can only work with the basics, so no tricks or anything sophisticated that I'm not supposed to know.

The problem with my program is that when a user enters 5 and 9 to be occupied it just prints "?????????????????????????". For example say I want to enter 10 cells and want 5 and 9 occupied, then the screen should look like this:

```
0123456789
     ?   ?
```

This is my work in full:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# define LENGTH 80

void display(int data[], int length);

int main()
{
    int input=0,i;
    int data[80];
    int index = 0;
    char occupied = '?';
    int cells,j,time;

    printf("Enter the number of cells:");
    scanf("%d", &cells);
    printf("Enter the number of cells you want occupied. The maximum number is 80. Type -1 to stop.:");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    printf("The original index is: %d",index);
    printf("\n");
    data[index] = input;
    index++;
    printf("The new index is: %d", index);
    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0; i < cells; i++) {
        printf("%d", i%10);
    }
    display(data, LENGTH);

}

void display(int data[], int length)
{
    int input=0,i;
    int index = 0;
    int cells,time;
    char occupied;


    if(input!=-1 && input <= 80) {
        data[index] = 1;
        occupied = '?';
        (char) data[index] = occupied;
    }
    else {
        data[index] = 0;
        occupied = ' ';
        (char) data[index] = occupied;
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
        printf("%c", data[index]);
    }
}
```

The printf and scanf lines about index was really just a sanity check for me.

Comment: That thread didn't help me at all.

Comment: What is the value of `output` after `scanf("%d", &input)`?

Comment: I posted that question in the middle of the night so I couldn't interact with any of the people until I woke up the next morning. The answer given wasn't related to what I was looking for. I just need someone to point out my errors in this code.

Comment: @ wannik: A cell that's occupied is assigned the value of 1. A cell that is not occupied is assigned a value of 0. For the cell that's occupied with 1, I need a "?" underneath it.

Comment: You might want to use a debugger to step through your code and see what's actually happening. You'll quickly find the problems.

Comment: I don't have the time to use a debugger or interpret it's use. I doubt that it will be very useful. I don't understand why no one is willing to point out what I could do to make the code better. I've tried everything and am looking for only some kind of advice.

Comment: You are asking a lot of very simple questions (some duplicates) and also haven't marked any as answers. You also claim to not have time to learn how to debug your code. I don't think you are going to find a lot of help if you aren't willing to put some effort into it yourself.

Comment: If you have worked on this for a week, you surely have had time to use a debugger. But in any case, have a look at your display function. You say `data[index] = 1; occupied = '?'; (char) data[index] = occupied;` What do you think that does?

Comment: Look I am not lazy. I do all of the work and plus more. I show up to class and really do participate in my learning by asking questions. Until today I had no idea what a debugger is for. Maybe I'm not too familiar with the way people are supposed to think in a programming class, I don't know but I am here to learn.

Comment: @ Bart: I believe it tells the program to assign 1 to data[index] or the input. For every input value, the program assigns it to '?'. So data[index] is assigned '?'

Comment: You indeed assign it '?'. `index` is equal to 0. You never do anything to it. The same goes for `input`. So once you get to printing your 80 characters in a loop at the end, all you do is output the question mark you put into `data[0]`. I would advice you to take pencil and paper and step by step write out what you want to do. Take a simple case. 4 positions for example. And then visualize for yourself what it is that needs to be done. Then go back to your code. P.s. is the code you posted exactly what you have? Because I don't think this compiles.

Comment: Yes, the code does compile. I'll do a flow chart to see what's going on.

Comment: Code as written in question does not compile.

Need_a_real_Job.c: In function ‘display’:
Need_a_real_Job.c:43:28: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
Need_a_real_Job.c:48:28: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Adding -Wall adds quite a few warnings about unused variables

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few bugs here. First off, you can scanf an array in one instance. Use a loop. Second, you are calling display() incorrectly. Use cells, not length. I've a working code here.

```
# include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int input=0,i;
    char data[80];
    int cells;
    int occupyMax = 0;
    int n = 0;

    printf("Enter the number of cells:");
    scanf("%d", &cells);

    printf("Enter number of cells you want occupied. The maximum number is 80:");
    scanf("%d", &occupyMax);

    // Ensure that # of occupied cells is lesser than max.
    if (occupyMax> cells)
    {
        printf("Error!");
        return;
    }

    // Init data to blank cells.
    for(i=0;i<80;i++)
    {
        data[i]=' ';
    }

    for( n = 0; n < occupyMax; n++) 
    {
        printf("Enter occupy cell number(Numbering starts at 0)\n");
        scanf("%d", &input );
        data[input] = '?';
    }

    // Display
    for(i = 0; i < cells; i++) 
    {
        printf("%d", i%10);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i < cells; i++) 
    {
        printf("%c", data[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should fix the code formatting, also this is a homework question and posting working code is not the best thing to do. Of course with it formatted like that you could just be trolling and I am missing the point.

Comment: Hi there, This is my first post and I was only trying to help. Having said that, point about code formatting is taken. Given that this is homework code, I've just corrected the requester's snippet, pointing out a few of his/her mistakes. Trust me, I wouldn't waste time trolling here :) I guess the policy here is to stop with pointing mistakes, rather than fixing their code in entirety. That point is also taken.

Comment: I didn't mean to be too harsh, sarcasm does not transfer well over the internet. But from your well typed reply I can tell you are going to do just fine here. Note, I'm not exactly a veteran here either.